# Python 2.7.9: No module named requests

Tags: python

I am writing a code in Python 2.7.9 for which I need the `requests` module. I installed the module using `sudo pip install requests` but still in python 2.7.9 I am getting an error as follows:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan  5 2016, 18:47:14) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I checked the installation location `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, it contains the `requests` package directory. The same thing works fine in `python3`, so I am guessing it's an installation error. How can I fix it ?

**EDIT:**

On executing `pip lists`, I could see `requests (2.1.9)` in the list. After I ran `pip uninstall requests` it shows `requests (2.2.1)` in `pip list`.

Comment: try printing `sys.path` to see where its looking ...

Comment: `['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

Comment: edit your original question ... .... but I dont see dist-packages in that list ... so how did you install requests?

Comment: sudo pip install requests

Comment: type `which pip` ? after you uninstalled it could you import it(since it still was in the pip list command)? my guess is you have an `apt-get install python-requests` conflicting with your `pip install requests` ... what if you try to download the zip, unzip it, and run `python2.7 setup.py install` ?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Did you install python normally using the package manager ? Which OS is this ?

Comment: @AJK Ubuntu 14.04, I had initially Python 2.7.6 but I installed 2.7.9 yesterday. I guess I have broken something

Comment: @bawejakunal How did you install python 2.7.9 ? The thing is by default in Ubuntu 14.04 would include dist-packages` folder. But your installation medium has removed it. My `sys.path` is `['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`

Comment: If I try to remove the `requests` 2.2.1 package then I get the following error. `Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, it seems you have installed python 2.7.9 using a method Ubuntu doesn't like. Because of this the `dist-packages` folder is not added to your `sys.path`. You could set the `PYTHONPATH` variable in your `.bashrc` (or other zshrc, etc) to add that folder to your `sys.path` by default.

Better method would be to use a library like `pyenv` (It handles all dependency issues flawlessly for multiple python versions) or a better supported ppa for the latest python where this problem shouldn't arise at all.

Also, you have 2 versions of `requests`. This seems to be because one is installed using `apt-get` (`sudo apt-get install python-requests`) and the other is from `pip` (`sudo pip install requests`). It would be good to remove one of them to avoid confusion.

Comment: I installed Python 2.7.9 building from the source.

Comment: Yep, the source python installation doesn't add `dist-packages` by default - because it is not a default location (only in Ubuntu). Try a ppa or pyenv - would be the best method. (I prefer pyenv as I can change the python version on the fly)